# Maven resolved version doesn't match version in transitive dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-jms

my project (A) is dependent on another proprietary project (B).  B lists `spring-jms` as a dependency like this (`spring.version` is `[4.3.9.RELEASE, 4.3.18.RELEASE]`):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

A -> B -> `spring-jms`

However, when I run `mvn clean dependency:tree -Dverbose=true` in my A, `spring-jms` comes back as 5.1.14.RELEASE, which is outside the range specified in B.  In the tree, spring-jms is listed twice and both entries have 5.1.14.RELEASE.

I don't have spring-jms listed in A.  I know I can add it to `dependencyManagement` in A to fix the issue, but I'd still like to know why it's resolving that version.

Below is the part of the tree showing `spring-jms`.  These are the only places it's listed.

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ project A ---
[INFO] project A
[INFO] +- project B
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.1.14.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 5.1.11.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.1.14.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 5.1.11.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
```

Comment: Maven's [dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) plugin may help.

Comment: Please see my edit.  The dependency tree doesn't show any other versions.

Comment: Did you use the `verbose` option? If not, try with that.

Answer (score 2):

It can happen if one of your dependencies is using 5.1.14.RELEASE. If you are using IntelliJ you can use maven section in the right to check your dependencies there you can find out that. Then you can use exclusion to remove that dependency

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.smaple.dependency</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
            <version>version</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>springjms</groupId>
                    ...
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `mvn dependency:tree` command and try to find all the appearances of spring-jms.

When maven resolves dependencies and if there are different versions of dependencies it will take the closest to the root in terms of depth in the tree of dependencies.

So if you project has the following tree:

```
YOUR_PROJECT
|___ <PROJECT_B>
|   |__spring-jms-v1 // depth = 2
|___spring-jms-v2    // depth = 1
```

Maven will take `spring-jms-v2` because its closer to the root

In any case, `mvn dependency:tree` will show both versions and full paths to the "root"

Comment: Please see my edit.  The dependency tree doesn't show any other versions.

Comment: You should run it on project-a;s pom. in the attached snippet I don't see any dependency of project A itself... Why?